# Fatal error: LCB_EINVAL with php sdk for couchbase

Tags: php, docker, couchbase

So I have couchbase on a docker container, and php and couchbase php sdk on another container.

when I try to access the couch base this is what happense:

I have a cluster named "`Analytics`"
there is a user as "`Administrator`" with "`123456`" password
I have a bucket called "`default`" and i've set a username and password to access it as "`default`" and  "`123456`"

this is what i have tried in php file to test the connection:

```
$cluster = new CouchbaseCluster("127.0.0.1:8091?detailed_errcodes=1");
// also tried as Administrator with 123456
$cluster->authenticateAs('default','123456');
// also tried as "default", "123456"
$myBucket = $cluster->openBucket('default');
```

but all of these credentials return this error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Couchbase\Exception: LCB_EINVAL: Invalid input/arguments in /usr/share/nginx/html/public/index.php on line 14

Couchbase\Exception: LCB_EINVAL: Invalid input/arguments in /usr/share/nginx/html/public/index.php on line 14
```

line 14 is this part:

```
$myBucket = $cluster->openBucket('default');
```

this is my sdk version and info:

```
Couchbase extension version is 2.6.1
couchbase
couchbase support   enabled
extension version   2.6.1
libcouchbase runtime version    2.10.5 (git: dabf6d58c2e89b4e75009a7f959e8ad30f85ff98)
libcouchbase headers version    2.10.5 (git: dabf6d58c2e89b4e75009a7f959e8ad30f85ff98)
igbinary transcoder disabled (install pecl/igbinary and rebuild pecl/couchbase)
zlib compressor enabled
Directive                        Local Value    Master Value
couchbase.log_level                     WARN    WARN
couchbase.encoder.format                json    json
couchbase.encoder.compression            off    off
couchbase.encoder.compression_threshold    0    0
couchbase.encoder.compression_factor     0.0    0.0
couchbase.decoder.json_arrays              0    0
couchbase.pool.max_idle_time_sec          60    60
```

what is my problem this couchbase really got me frustrated.

Comment: i could really use some help. people please.

Comment: What version of Couchbase Server are you using? What docker command did you use to start Couchbase Server?

Comment: well i used `latest` tag so it should be `enterprise-6.0.3` version. i used `docker-compose-build && docker-compose up -d` to build and run it. i don't know if there is another command to do so?

Comment: Please post your docker-compose.yml file.